# The Summary of the Count Number of Each Categories from Multiple Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, sum, pivot-table, vlookup, countif

Let's say I have 11 different sheets in one Google Sheet workbook. Each of the sheets look like this:

| customer | reason for losing |
| --- | --- |
| PT A | uncompetitive price |
| PT B | by project |
| PT C | NG quality |
| PT D | late delivery |
| PT E | term of payment |
| PT F | late delivery |

I want to count the number of each `reason for losing` categories and create a new sheet page to summarize the count of each `reason for losing` categories.

I expect the output will look like this:

| reason for losing | count |
| --- | --- |
| uncompetitive price | 1 |
| by project | 1 |
| late delivery | 2 |
| NG quality | 1 |
| term of payment | 1 |

I'm thinking of using `VLOOKUP`, `SUM`, or `COUNTIF` but still not sure how to create the best formula. Can anyone help me to build the formula?

Thank u in advance.

Comment: To summarize data from all 11 sheet, you need `VSTACK()` to stack data then use `QUERY()` function to get desired calculation/aggregation.

Answer (score 1):

Use `QUERY()` function.

```
=QUERY(B:B,"select B, count(B) 
where B is not null 
group by B 
label count(B) 'Count'",1)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Adding to @Harun24hr, you can use VSTACK or curly brackets if you want to have a summary sheet of the 11 pages:

```
=QUERY({Sheet1!B:B;Sheet2!B2:B;Sheet3!B2:B....},"select Col1, count(Col1) 
where Col1 is not null 
group by Col1 
label count(Col1) 'Count'",1)
```

One extra option instead of using curly brackets if you have a range with all the sheets names is to use REDUCE and INDIRECT to get all ranges dinamically to get new sheets' names. Guessing that range is in D column of your summary sheet:

```
=QUERY(REDUCE("reason for losing", TOCOL(D:D,1), LAMBDA(a,v,{a;INDIRECT (v&"!B2:B")})),"select Col1, count(Col1) 
where Col1 is not null 
group by Col1 
label count(Col1) 'Count'",1)
```